# Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.FilePath' cannot be assigned to

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Basically I retrieved the records from the table and wanted to updated one column.

```
var query = cdrContext.tabless.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
                                .OrderBy(c => c.TimeStationOffHook)
                                .Skip(size)
                                .Take(pageSize)
                                .Select(c => new { c.FilePath, c.FileName })
                                .ToList();
```

So this query has only two fields: FilePath and FileName, then next I want to assign FilePath = null;

```
foreach (var y in query)
{
     y.FilePath = null;
}
cdrContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then I got an error:

```
Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.FilePath' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select from query anonymous class. You cannot set properties of anonymous class. To do what you want you should get whole entity:

```
var query = cdrContext.tabless.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
                                .OrderBy(c => c.TimeStationOffHook)
                                .Skip(size)
                                .Take(pageSize)
                                .ToList();

foreach (var y in query)
{
     y.FilePath = null;
}
cdrContext.SaveChanges();
```